# Quest markers stuck on settlement workbenches

Tags: fallout-4

I went over to help two settlements as part of the Form Ranks quest, one to build a recruitment beacon, and another to secure a workbench. I did just those, but the quest markers were still stuck on the workbenches. Is this just something that can be fixed with a restart or hotfix? Or am I going to have to be stuck with this forever?

Comment: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Form_Ranks On the wikia page it is stated, that this quest will stay active until you have 8 settlements. Have you tried getting 8 settlements on your side and see if the markers still exist?

Comment: @Bounce I have an alliance with 8 settlements, but I forgot to mark the mission as an active one while helping the eighth. I went over to two other settlements to try again, but then this issue arose.

Comment: It also says there that "If the Sole Survivor worked with the Brotherhood of Steel or the Railroad to complete The Molecular Level, they'll have to complete Inside Job, which becomes accessible right after starting this quest. Otherwise, this quest will never have enough settlements to finish." Does that apply to you? Also, marking the quest as active or not only affects your map, it won't affect objective completion.

Comment: @DCShannon. Yes, I completed Inside Job for both the Brotherhood and Minutemen. I even completed Defend the Castle, but restarted to my starting point beforehand due to the rising on the unprovoked BOS hostility issue. After that, I had to start over, but no matter how many settlements I helped, Form Ranks was never completed.

Comment: Defend the Castle is supposed to trigger after Form Ranks is completed. To check, did you complete Form Ranks, complete Defend the Castle, then load a save before completing Form Ranks, and now you can't? That's definitely odd. Did you capture different settlements the second time around?

Comment: @DCShannon  No, before I loaded the save before completing Form Ranks, I completed Returning the Favor, thus completing the quest. After restarting, I repeated the action, but didn't finish the quest. The only difference between both actions was that the second time around, I'd forgotten to mark Form Ranks as an active quest.